# INSERT INTO table SELECT from another table doesnt give id's

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to figure out how to give data from select to insert into in one statement.

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO $table2 ($fields2) SELECT $fields$table$whereOrderBy";
echo $statement;
return $datas = $this->query($statement, $fields2, false, null); //fields2 is attributes..

INSERT INTO match_players (match_id,team_id,team_player_id,name,squad_number,display_order,status ) SELECT id,team1_id,210,SUEMA,13,23,first_eleven FROM matches WHERE team1_id = 1 AND is_deleted = 0

//it doesnt show 'team1_id' is 1....
```

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array,
>   string given in /var/opt/lampp/htdocs/testLAB/query/query.php on line
>   59

```
$db->insertSelect('all', ['fields2' => ['match_id', 'team_id', 'team_player_id', 'name', 'squad_number', 'display_order', 'status'], 'fields' => ['id', 'team1_id', $team_player_id, $name, $squad_number, $display_order, $default_status], 'conditions' => ['team1_id' => $id, 'is_deleted' => 0]]);
```

Error code:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array,
>   string given in /var/opt/lampp/htdocs/testLAB/query/query.php on line
>   59

function: `function prepare($statement, $attributes, $one = false, $fetch = null)`
59: `$res = $req->execute($attributes);`

var_dump($attriputes):

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "TYRAJYRA" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "44" [3]=> string(13) "not_available" [4]=> string(2) "33" [5]=> string(16) "img/default.jpeg" } 
INSERT INTO match_players (match_id,team_id,team_player_id,name,squad_number,display_order,status ) SELECT id,team1_id,211,TYRAJYRA,44,33,not_available FROM matches WHERE team1_id = 1 AND is_deleted = 0
string(71) "match_id,team_id,team_player_id,name,squad_number,display_order,status "
```

Comment: try `var_dump($attributes)` to see what inside, the error is clear: `$attributes` should be an array, you pass a String variable.

Comment: @catcon tryed var_dump and got array.. Edited post..